# Clone an object passed from a parent component in a child component - React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, api, object, react-hooks

I used spread operator and useState to clone an object passed from the parent component but it returned an empty object. Any helps would be appreciated. Thanks :)

```js
const Parent = () =>{

  //I fetch data from my custom hook
  const {data} = useFetch(url)

  return(
    <Child data={data}/>
  )
}
```

```js
const Child = ({data}) =>{
   const [copyData, setCopyData] = useState({...data});
   
   
   //it returns an empty object here
   const testing = () =>{
    console.log(copyData)
   }
   
   return(
    <button onClick={testing}>Testing</button>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time your component renders the fetch request won't have completed yet so data will be null (use `const {data, loading} = useFetch(url);` to see this)

Your child component then uses that null to set the default value for copyData, and you never update it.

You need to add a useEffect to call setCopyData every time data changes. Something like this maybe:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setCopyData({...data});
}, [data]);
```